# How JSONEachRow can support binary data?

Tags: string, encoding, binary, clickhouse

This document suggests that JSONEachRow Format can handle binary data.

http://www.devdoc.net/database/ClickhouseDocs_19.4.1.3-docs/interfaces/formats/#jsoneachrow

From my understanding binary data can contain any bytes and because of this data can represent anything and it can break the JSON structure.

For example, a string may contain some bytes that may represent a quote if interpreted in UTF-8 or some invalid bytes.

So,

How are they achieving it?

How do they know when that string is actually ending?

At the end the DB needs to interpret the command and values, they must be using some encoding to do that.

Please correct me if I am wrong somehow.

Comment: `Unlike the JSON format, there is no substitution of invalid UTF-8 sequences. Any set of bytes can be output in the rows.` - I guess it means that invalid UTF8 sequences/bytes are not removed (substituted) in text; the end of string stored in the table is known to the internal representation, and the end of string in JSON is known because values are wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: Ok, so i guess they must be ignoring if any non utf8 char is present. Instead of throwing errors, they must be keeping it as it is.

Comment: Apart from this they must also be escaping any bytes that repesent chars like quotes in utf8.